# How to wrap every WCF call in a try-catch block

Tags: wcf, delegates, try-catch

I have a website where I need to make asynchronous calls to a WCF service.
I want to wrap each call in a try-catch block so I can deal with TimeoutExceptions and CommunicationExceptions.

However, I don't want to just copy-paste the exact same try-catch block every time I make a call to my service.  Is there some way I can use delegates to only write the try-catch block once?  I also still want to capture the exception messages.

I want to call it like:

```
// This method returns void
TryCatchHelper(x => x.WCFMethod1(param1, param2));

// This method has a return value but no params
var returnValue = TryCatchHelper(x => x.WCFMethod2());
```

EDIT:
Here's what my code looks like now:

```
User GetUser(int Id)
{
    User returnUser = null;

    try
    {
        // Open WCF channel, etc.
        returnUser = myWCFClient.GetUser(Id);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException exception)
    {
        Log(exception.Message);
        // Abort WCF factory
    }
    catch (CommunicationException exception)
    {
        Log(exception.Message);
        // Abort WCF factory
    } 

    return returnUser;
}
```

I don't want to use this same try-catch block in every single method I set up in my repository.  I tried doing something like this, but it gave me an error on the params.  I know I'm not using them correctly, but I need a way to define a delegate that can stand in for all of the WCF method calls I want to make:

```
delegate object WCFAction(params object[] parameters);

object DoWCFAction(WCFAction action, params object[] parameters)
{
    object returnValue = null;

    try
    {
        // Open WCF channel, etc.
        returnValue = action(parameters);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException exception)
    {
        Log(exception.Message);
        // Abort WCF factory
    }
    catch (CommunicationException exception)
    {
        Log(exception.Message);
        // Abort WCF factory
    } 

    return returnValue;
}

void MainMethod()
{
    // Compiler error
    User user = DoWCFAction(GetUser, 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to do this with delegates and failed?  If so, please show us the code that isn't working.  If not, please go research it before asking a question on SO.

Comment: What do you want your `catch` block to do? Log the exception and return what exactly (for methods with a return value)? Retry?

Comment: I want to log the errors somewhere so admins can look at timeout and connection issues.  Added code for what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a class like this.  Sorry there are two exception handlers here, not one:

```
class Logger
{
    // handle wcf calls that return void
    static public void ExecWithLog(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    // handle wcf calls that return a value
    static public T ExecWithLog<T>(Func<T> action)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        try
        {
            result = action();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e);
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Log(Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

}
```

Then, to call your methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.ExecWithLog(() => DoSomethingReturnVoid());
    Logger.ExecWithLog(() => DoSomethingReturnVoidParamInt(5));
    int a = Logger.ExecWithLog<int>(() => DoSomethingReturnInt());
    string b = Logger.ExecWithLog<string>(() => DoSomethingReturnStringParamInt(5));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the use of Func<T> was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to do this with WCF is with Extensions. Take a look at these articles on WCF Extensions:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx

Comment: this should be the answer